# How to setup a fixed height on a Bootstrap Mobile Bottom Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed bottom footer that acts as an "iphone-style" navbar.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="row" id="bottomNav">

    <a href="/merchants"><div class="col-xs-4 text-center icon-flag"></div></a>
    <a href="/credits"><div class="col-xs-4 text-center icon-credit"></div></a>
    <a href="/profiles"><div class="col-xs-4 text-center icon-user"></div></a> 

   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the original exmaple:

http://www.bootply.com/108286#

I did a change to the original code in order to make the full div a link. I just moved the `<a>` tag outside of the div.

The problem I have is that the height of the navbar is not enough and part of the icons are placed outside of the navbar.

[image]

I have tried creating a custom class

```
.navbar-custom{
   height: 200px;
}
```

and assign it to the div:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-custom">
```

And it did not work. Neither to the row:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-custom">
```

Any idea?

UPDATE:
The custom class does work. My bad. The thing is that the icons or fixed to the top of the row instead of the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding your a  to the inside of the your navbar?

you can use the bootstrap examples for reference:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

think about the structure of your navbar html when doing this.

Comment: I have tried, but I can not get the <li> items to extend to the full of the navbar width.

Comment: I have added your code above into the link you posted and it seems to work fine. are you able to show a full copy of your code? on codepen or jsFiddle or something like that

Comment: I have it hosted in heroku http://sheltered-chamber-1367.herokuapp.com/ you need to sign-up in order to see the nav-footer. Thanks